# JavaFX 8 - Printing 3d scene

Tags: java, printing, javafx-8

I am trying to use the JavaFX 8 printing API and I am running into problems when I try to print any scene/node that contains any sort of 3D content.  I have been searching both here and other sites for an answer and haven't been able to find anything to help.

If the node contains only 2D content, the scene will print on my selected printer without issue.  But if I add a single 3D object to the scene, the whole thing fails to print - without any error but without any content.  If I am printing to a printer, a blank page is "printed" and if I am printing to a document printer, I get an empty document.

I have tried using the AWT printing mechanism to convert the node to a WritableImage and then to a BufferedImage for printing.  This works in that it prints but we aren't happy with the quality that we get from it.

My print caller is fairly standard at this stage -

```
private void doPrintFX() {
    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
    PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(
            Paper.A3, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);

    final double scaleFactor = computeScaleFactor(pageLayout.getPrintableWidth(),
            pageLayout.getPrintableHeight(),
            sceneNode.getBoundsInParent().getWidth(),
            sceneNode.getBoundsInParent().getHeight());
    if (scaleFactor != 0) {
        sceneNode.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor));
    }

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);
    if (job != null) {
        System.out.println("Printing to " + job.getPrinter().getName());
        boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, sceneNode);
        if (success) {
            job.endJob();
        }
    }
}
```

I have scaled back the node to be a very simple scene containing a couple of rectangles and a cylinder. The code I am currently using is:

```
    Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(50, 150);
    cylinder.setLayoutX(250);
    cylinder.setLayoutY(100);
    canvas.getDrawingPane().getChildren().add(cylinder);

    Rectangle item = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 50);
    item.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    item.setFill(null);
    canvas.getDrawingPane().getChildren().add(item);

    item = new Rectangle(75, 75, 100, 50);
    item.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    item.setFill(null);
    canvas.getDrawingPane().getChildren().add(item);
```

The canvas.getDrawingPane is a Pane and is what is being sent to the print function.

Can anyone advise what might be wrong with what I am doing?  Does the JavaFX print API support printing of 3D nodes?  Thank you.

Comment: You could try asking this question on the [openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).

Comment: Thank you jewelsea. I have asked there as well.

Comment: @jewelsea.  have you heard or know of another good way to print a scenegraph with 3d nodes?

Comment: No Brian, I have never used the printing functions of JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

Just answering my own question for anyone else who might be interested.

I have found out that 3D printing is not supported in FX 8.  It has been put down for a possible enhancement for version 9.

Comment: But thank you for posting this anyway. This my first time lookinf at printing code and it looks very much like printing in swing.

Comment: So is there no way to improve the resolution of the bufferedImage?  Is there any update on ability to print or store in another object the bufferedImage for quality 3D nodes to print?